# SEVERE: Exception starting filter CORS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cors

I have RESTful web service deployed on tomcat' the web service is working fine in the client/server on same domain scenario' but I am required to make the Web Service available from cross domain' for this purpose I have used CORS filter.

I have included filter's jars in both myProjects/lib and tomcat/lib' and also have included following in my web.xml file of web service project'

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>Accept, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Last-Modified</param-value>
</init-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when I try to start the web service I get following error regarding CORS filter:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter CORS
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thetransactioncompany/util/PropertyParseException
at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.init(CORSFilter.java:100)
```

kindly guide me to figure out what is wrong with this situation'

Comment: Looks like some issue in initialization of CORSFilter. I suggest you to remove any init parameters and try by default , if it works.

Comment: thanx for replying but it is not working so I am now switching to jsonp to tackle cross domain issue

Answer (score 16):

You need to add java-properties-utils-1.7.1.jar file to the classpath too as the cors filter has a dependancy on it.

http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-411787350

Comment: Should't this be packaged together with tomcat then? (e.g. in the .deb packages for Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: BTW, just tried adding it to Tomcat's lib directory but that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, adding these 2 jar files in the tomcat lib folder solved the issue:

- cors-filter-2.5.jar
- java-property-utils-1.10.jar

Answer (score 0):

It might have been a version issue. I had the same problem and it turns out this filter requires at minimum Tomcat version 7.0.41 to work, according to: http://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html

As reference, Debian 7.8 ships Tomcat 7.0.28, which does not support native CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the problem was that the maven dependencies had been deleted from the `Deployment Assembly` section in project `properties`. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had same prob but in ma case, 
first, my server status was unbound, so I changed it through 'Build path'
But still didn't work.. 
my friend checked and he found 
Eclipse's 'Build Automatically' function. 
then it worked well !